# SearchGuard community edition - Rest API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, search-guard

I am wondering if SearchGuard community edition has the rest api feature ?

Has anyone with the community version found a way to manage internal users, roles and so on without using the rest api.

Answer (score 2):

The REST API is an Enterprise feature so you cannot use it in the Community Edition.

For managing users, roles and permissions in the Community Edition you need to use the sgadmin command line tool:

https://docs.search-guard.com/latest/sgadmin

You can also find some usage examples in the Search Guard documentation:

https://docs.search-guard.com/latest/sgadmin-examples

If you have used the demo installer, it will generate a preconfigured sgadmin call in the plugins/search-guard-6/tools directory which you can simply use:

```
./sgadmin_demo.sh
```

Comment: Thank you @Jochen. But I do not need to run sgadmin across all nodes? Since they all have Search Guard plugin installed. Wondering if run sgadmin on one node when adding new user will be enough ?

Comment: You just need to run it on one node in the cluster. The Search Guard configuration is kept in a specially secured Elasticsearch index, so changes will propagate throughout the cluster automatically and nearly immediately. The REST API and sgadmin do the same in the end: Pushing configuration changes to the Search Guard index. So while the GUI might be more convenient to use, the end result will be the same with both approaches.